# Performing a Transaction Log Backup on a Live Database

Tags: backup, sql-server-2012, transaction-log

I have a server 2012 database that has a transaction log that is growing at a rapid rate. i have a job that runs once a day after production hours which backs up the log file and shrinks it.

The number of transactions being processed has increased exponentially therefore the log is growing at such a rapid rate.

what i would like to know is .... is it safe to do a backup during production hours?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly safe to do a backup during production hours. You should be doing multiple log backups per hour, not one per day. The duplicate link will clarify your understanding of what the transaction log is and why you need to back it up more frequently.

Comment: STOP BACKING UP AND SHRINKING THE LOG FILE. Either change your recovery mode to simple or start backing up your log more frequently.

Comment: Thanks for you comments guys. i have set the transaction log backups to take place every hour it seems to have fixed the problem